# Problem memoizing Allcombination sum to target in java

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have been practising recursive function in java and need some help from java expert. The recursive function is working. However, i am having problem memoizing it because there are value that keep changing after it is put into the memo.

Due to that, the memo final value is wrong. Thus, i cannot memoize it. I have used debugger many times but i still cannot solve it. Anyone can guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

```
static private List<List<Integer>> allCombinationDP(int[] candidates, int target, Map<Integer,List<List<Integer>>> memo ){
    List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    // Map<Integer,List<List<Integer>>> memo = new HashMap<>();
    
    if (target <0) return null;
    if (target ==0) {
      List<List<Integer>> ansSet = new ArrayList<>();
      ansSet.add(new ArrayList<>());
      return ansSet;
    }

    for (int i=0, n=candidates.length; i<n;i++){
      int remainder = target - candidates[i];
      List<List<Integer>> result = allCombinationDP(candidates, remainder,memo);
      if (result != null){
        for (int j =0, m=result.size(); j<m;j++) {
          result.get(j).add( candidates[i] );
        }
        temp.addAll(new ArrayList<>(result));
      }
    }
    memo.put(target, new ArrayList<>(temp));
    System.out.println(memo.toString());
    return temp;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] candidates = {1,2,3};
    int target = 3;
    
    System.out.println(allCombinationDP(candidates, target, new HashMap<>()) );
  }
```

The  output is
`{1=[ [1] ] }`
`{1=[ [1, 1] ], 2=[ [1, 1], [2] ] }`
`{1=[ [1] ], 2=[ [1, 1, 1], [2, 1] ] }`
`{1=[ [1, 2] ],  2=[ [1, 1, 1], [2, 1] ],  3=[ [1, 1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3] ] }`

`[  [1, 1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3] ]`

I am expecting the output to be
`{1=[ [1] ] }`
`{1=[ [1] ], 2=[ [1, 1], [2] ] }`
`{1=[ [1] ], 2=[ [1, 1], [2] ] }`
`{1=[ [1] ], 2=[ [1, 1], [2] ], 3=[ [1, 1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3] ] }`

`[  [1, 1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3] ]`

Comment: I think the main weirdness comes from `result.get(j).add( candidates[i] );` - you are modifying `result` and due to a partial shallow copy, also the stuff inside memo. (try printing out memo before and after this statement)

Comment: Yeah. You are right. The issue is with partial shallow copy. I solved the problem by using deep copy. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
  static private List<List<Integer>> allCombinationDP(int[] candidates, int target, Map<Integer,List<List<Integer>>> memo ){
    List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    
    if (target <0) return null;
    if (target ==0) {
      List<List<Integer>> ansSet = new ArrayList<>();
      ansSet.add(new ArrayList<>());
      return ansSet;
    }
    if (memo.containsKey(target)){
      return new ArrayList<>(memo.get(target).stream().map(ArrayList::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    } 

    for (int i=0, n=candidates.length; i<n;i++){
      int remainder = target - candidates[i];
      List<List<Integer>> result = allCombinationDP(candidates, remainder,memo);
      if (result != null){
        for (int j =0, m=result.size(); j<m;j++) {
          result.get(j).add( candidates[i] );
        }
        temp.addAll(new ArrayList<>(result));
      }
    }
    List<List<Integer>> newTemp = temp.stream().map(ArrayList::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    memo.put(target, new ArrayList<>( newTemp ));
    System.out.println(memo.toString());
    return temp;
  }
```

With some help from telegram friends, i managed to solve my own problem. The problem is that i only shallow copied `result` which is `List<List<Integer>>` when i put the value into memo.

Deep copying is required for `List<List<Integer>>`.

Shallow copy: `memo.put(target, new ArrayList<>(temp));`

Deep copy : `memo.put(target, new ArrayList<>( temp.stream().map(ArrayList::new).collect(Collectors.toList()) ));`

Do remember to deep copy when you are returning value from memo also.